# Filter to remove the default password on "Your Profile" page

Tags: theme-development, users, profiles

Whenever I go to my "Your Profile" page to edit any of the settings other than the password, I have to manually empty out the password field to avoid errors/nags.

Is there a filter I can place in functions.php that will empty the password field by default?

Comment: Doesn't it comes empty by default for you?? I've never seen other kind of behavior... Also, there's almost no filters in /wp-admin/edit-user.php, the only relevant being `show_password_fields` that can be used to hide the fields

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52494/how-did-you-incorporate-woocommerce-in-your-own-wordpress-theme/59115#59115

Comment: It's because you opted to "remember password" in your browser. Some are smarter than others. In this case, it's pre-filling your profile as well as the login form. Either way, it's not WordPress!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the password fields should appear "empty" on the "Your Profile" page.

Make sure your Wordpress installation is up to date and try deactivating any plugins that extend the user profile page and commenting out any code in your functions.php file. There is most likely a conflict with one of these plugins.

Comment: Must be my setup then. Maybe chrome playing tricks on me. I now see it doesn't happen in FF. Only in Chrome.

Comment: I use Chrome and haven't had any issues like this. Did you find which plugin was causing the conflict?